# SQL Insert from a select and a math operation

Tags: sql, database, libreoffice-base

I am using LibreOffice base because I need to use the same database in Windows and in OSX.

I have a table with a hundreds of **CLIENT_ID** as Primary Key and **CLIENT_NAME** as field. The primary key has a length of 6 chars:

**CLxxxx**

I'd like to be able to insert a new client and to do it using a single SQL statement, no VBA or PHP. Like using an autonumber.

What I'm trying to do is this:

1) Get the highest key, remove the "CL" from it. E.g. for CL0344 I need 0344

2) Add 1 to the highest key to have the new key for the new client: 0355

3) Insert the new CLIENT in the table

The first point is simple to accomplish using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT(CLIENT_ID,4) AS LAST_RECORD FROM CLIENTS
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID DESC
```

But how can I add 1 to the result of this select and use the same statement to make the insert?

Comment: In order to add 1, you need the value as integer, CAST(RIGHT(CLIENT_ID,4) as integer). Then you can do + 1. Afterwards cast back to char (and concat with CL.) Just a warning, what happens for CL9999?

Comment: I hope I will never have 9999 clients to follow ;)

Comment: My advice is to change datatype to integer (you don't need CL). Then you can have lots of clients to follow!

Comment: I am using the "CL" suffix because I have 3 tables: Clients, Contacts, ContactsForClients that connects the two tables for a many to many relation. Clients use the "CL" suffix, Contacts the "CN" suffix and in ContactsForClients I store keys like this: CL0042CN0023 so by looking just as the key I can go back to Client or the Contact.

Comment: Don't do that. Use the integer datatype and store ContactsForClients as a two column pair (two integer columns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:-

```
 SELECT CAST(RIGHT(MAX(CLIENT_ID),4) AS INTEGER) + 1
 FROM CLIENTS;
```

Comment: Why ORDER BY for a one row result? Can the integer value 1 be added to the character value '1234' in libreoffice?

Comment: jarlh is right, It seems libre office doesn't like the order by in the query. Without it the query works and I get my 345. So objective 1 and 2 are accomplished. How can I accomplish also my latest point using a single query?

Comment: Insert and select within the same table cant be done at same time. You have to done it seperately. Better to make a transaction.

Comment: Don't forget to cast back to char, add leading 0's, and finally put 'CL' first. A bit tricky since you can have 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits. (With integer columns this would have been so easy...)

Comment: Doing with integer columns I could simply set is as autonumber to avoid the select+math operation part. Buy everywhere I look it is written it is always better to avoid to use autonumber. This is why I went with the "CL" / "CN" suffix